# Appending a CSSStyleSheet with insertRule() yields an empty element

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
const sheet = styleElement.sheet;

const rule = `@font-face {
  font-family: '${fontIdentifier}';
  src: url('${font.url}');
}`

sheet.insertRule(rule);

console.log(sheet); //has rule(s)
console.log(styleElement); //empty - <style></style>
```

How can i get this `@font-face` rule to show up in this created style element?

Comment: What use would you make of this? If you need the rule as CSS text, you'd get  `rule.cssText`, if you want all the rules in the `<style>`'s sheet you'd do `[...sheet.cssRules].map(rule => rule.cssText)`, but setting the `textContent` of the `<style>` seems rather useless no?

Comment: Why do you care about the actual style element's content, as long as it works?

Comment: It is not intuitive, i didn't realize it actually works.

Comment: Could you clarify where your knowledge about this topic comes from? This doesn't seem like a daily use case and simple googling did not make it obvious what actually will happen after `insertRule` what is the difference between a rule and text etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `<style/>` element actually works if its sheet contains the rules.